# What is wrong with this line of java code?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, binary-tree

```
if (current.leftChild.iData != '+' && current.rightChild.iData != '+')
```

For this line of code i am trying to check if the leftChild of the current node and the rightChild of the current node both == '+' Or character plus sign. If either of them do not = the character + i want to execute other code. I am getting a null pointer exception for this line and the method i use to call this line of code. 
iData is just the information inside the node.

Comment: Either `current`, `current.leftChild`, or `current.rightChild` is null. If `iData` is a `Character` rather than a `char`, it could also be null. Print them out one by one and see which it is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are getting a null pointer exception that means either the following cases. 
1. current is null. 
2. leftChild is null/ rightChild is null. 
3. iData is null

But since you haven't provided a lot of details. I won't be able to help you.

Comment: if iData is null will you still get a NPE?

Comment: Yes. As you are comparing with the primitive type, you need to unbox the object type. To do this you JVM call method on object instance. If instance is not set then NPE is raised.

Comment: @NiklasB I just tested this, actually if a primitive type is null, it won't compile. But if a object type is null, it still compares with null and +. in users case if iData is null it will enter thsi if statement.

Comment: @Vash: Okay, what Kevin said is what I initially thought would happen. No NPE, instead the `!=` will return `true`.

Comment: @Kevin, the statement you have used is incorect. The primitive types by definition can not be null.

Comment: @Vash therefore it won't compile.

Comment: @Kevin, so the statement if a primitive type is null is not logically correct ;-). NVM.

Comment: @Vash but the program won't compile. if i wanted to set a int number = null. It is not correct, but doens't mean i can't type number = null. Therefore I feel like telling the user it won't compile is more correct.

Comment: So the solution is to say, that user can not assign to primitive type null value because the code will not compile. But leave that behind us. What I do not fully comprehend from you answer is that you claim if the iData is type of Character and is null then the code will not throw NPE?

Comment: @Vash char or Character? those are different as char is primitive and Character is object

Comment: @Vash maybe I am getting what you are saying. Since you cannot set the char class to null but Character to null. you can still compare (Character) null == '+'. But you CANNOT compare char == null or set a char == null. That gives compilation errors.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9936/discussion-between-vash-and-kevin)

Answer (score 2):

Either `current.leftChild` or `current.rightChild` (or `current` itself) is not being set properly and is `null`. Trying to access the members of `null` results in a `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 1):

If `current`, `current.leftChild` or `current.rightChild` is `null`, you will get a `NullPointerException`.
You need to perform a null check first.

Answer (score 0):

Use breakpoints to see the values of current.leftChild.iData and current.rightChild.iData.
Or you can write:

> System.out.println("leftChild: " + current.leftChild.iData);
>
> System.out.println("leftChild: " + current.rightChild.iData);

You will need to check the changes to these values because somewhere in your code it has set them to null. Once they are null, the system will give you the NullPointerException because those objects no longer exists.

Answer (score 0):

First of all try printing each piece of that to find out what is null, you should get an NPE when you get to the piece that is causeing you trouble, this will seperate left and right into seperate failures.  Note that if you make these seperate lines and both are failing you will only get the failure for the first one.

Now:

> if (current.leftChild.iData != '+' && current.rightChild.iData != '+')   For >this line of code i am trying to check if the leftChild of the current node and >the rightChild of the current node both == '+' Or character plus sign. If >either of them do not = the character + i want to execute other code

The code you wrote will not (once its not throwing exceptions) test what you say you want it to.  You said you want to see if either is != to '+', but this code only tests if both are != '+', therefore you are missing some conditions which I believe that you inteded to catch.  In fact if you really want to execute *other* code if either does not equal '+' then what you want is

```
if (current.leftChild.iData == '+' && current.rightChild.iData == '+')
{
    //code you execute if both are equal to '+'
}
else
{
    //code you execute if either (or both) is not equal to '+'
}
```